# Linear velocity vs distance moved in one frame

Tags: javascript, box2d

I'm trying to move a KinematicBody by a specific distance by calculating the corresponding velocity needed to move it all the way across in one frame. Below is a piece of pseudocode describing what I'm doing:

```
var v = 0;
function update(){
    // do update
    world.Step(1/60, 10, 10);

    // do rendering stuff

    // set linear velocity to v
    objectBody.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0, v));
    // reset v to 0
    v = 0;

    // wait 16.6ms

    update();
}

function moveBy(n){
    v = n * 60;  // set velocity to be n units/sec
}
```

Calling `moveBy(300)` does not actually move it by 300 units. It does move down, but the distance is not 300 units.

Why is that and what is a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a maximum limit of how far a KinematicBody can move in a step to prevent tunnelling. To solve this I had to scale down everything.